# How to get typeof function properties in Julia

Tags: types, julia

How to get the `typeof` properties in Julia

```
a = reshape(1:15,3,5)

b = typeof(a)
Base.ReshapedArray{Int64, 2, UnitRange{Int64}, Tuple{}}
```

How can I get 'Int64' property of 'b'?

'2' is the number of dimensions. right. How to get that info from 'b'?

Comment: `eltype(a)` gives you the element type, `Int64`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is the function `ndims` to get the number of dimensions of an array, and `eltype` for the return type:

```
julia> a = reshape(1:15,3,5);

julia> ndims(a)
2

julia> eltype(a)
Int64
```

more generally to get type parameters, you can use multiple dispatch:

```
julia> my_eltype(x::AbstractArray{T}) where T = T
my_eltype (generic function with 1 method)

julia> my_eltype(a)
Int64

julia> my_ndims(x::AbstractArray{T,N}) where {T,N} = N
my_ndims (generic function with 1 method)

julia> my_ndims(a)
2
```

Comment: Can you answer completely.